# Select only rows with each word beginning with capital letter being output

Tags: sql

I am trying to output data from a SQL database for only values where each word begins with a capital letter. If I have the Products column with values of "Product One Apple" and "Product two banana", I would only want to output any values such as "Product One Apple". I am not wanting to update any data, just manipulate the data output. Is this possible without the use of a function, or will this require one?

Comment: The handling of case sensitivity depends on the database.  You need to provide a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you are using SQL Server:-

**`Table Creation:`**

```
create table YourTable(id int identity(1,1),YourColumn varchar(100));

insert into YourTable(YourColumn)
select 'One Letter' Name union all
select 'another One' union all
select 'lower case' union all
select 'Upper case Sensitiive charecters'
```

**`Fetch Data:`**

```
with SPosition as
(select patindex('% %',YourColumn) SPosition, YourColumn from YourTable 
union all
select SPosition+patindex('% %',substring(YourColumn, SPosition+1, len(YourColumn))) SPosition, YourColumn from SPosition
where patindex('% %',substring(YourColumn, SPosition+1, len(YourColumn)))>0
),SelectedWords as(
select substring(YourColumn,SPosition+1,1) StartingPosition,Case When substring(YourColumn,SPosition+1,1) Collate Latin1_General_CS_AI=upper(substring(YourColumn,SPosition+1,1))
then isnull(nullif(ltrim(rtrim(substring(YourColumn,SPosition+1,patindex('% %',substring(YourColumn, SPosition+1, len(YourColumn)))))),''),
substring(YourColumn,SPosition+1,len(YourColumn)))
else null end Words,
SPosition,YourColumn from SPosition
union all
select substring(YourColumn,1,1),Case When substring(YourColumn,1,1) Collate Latin1_General_CS_AI=upper(substring(YourColumn,1,1))
then isnull(nullif(ltrim(rtrim(substring(YourColumn,1,patindex('% %',substring(YourColumn, 1, len(YourColumn)))))),''),
substring(YourColumn,1,len(YourColumn)))
else null end,
1,YourColumn from YourTable
)
select YourColumn,String_Agg(Words,',') from SelectedWords where Words is not null
group by YourColumn
```

**You can run this code by [Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5abc2226dbd5632fb2596fc465ae0b7e)**

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do with following query

```
Select CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(colunm_name,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(column_name,2))) AS Name from table_name;
```

Comment: That is sort of what I had before from doing research. Unfortunately, maybe I cannot explain this very well. I am only wanting to output values that have the first letter of each word capitalized. If I have "ABC One Two THREE" it will be displayed, but if I have "ABC One Two tHREE" it will not. This is where it is very confusing for me, as I am not too familiar with functions if I would need to use one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ASCII representation number of the first letter, and validate the range between 65 and 90, which are the position that upper letters have in the ASCII table (ex. "@" represents the 64th position):

```
select d.Name, LEFT(d.Name, 1),ASCII(LEFT(d.Name, 1)) 
from (
select 'One Letter' Name union all
select 'another One' union all
select 'lower case' union all
select 'Upper'
)d
where ASCII(LEFT(d.Name, 1)) between 65 and 90 --Here the validation
```

If you want to review the ASCII table (decimal position), check this link: [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)